# javascript----OOP

Tags: javascript

```
 var  changeUrl={
                'baseUrl':...,
                ......,
                'getDomain' : function(url){
                       .......
       }
                'InitWebLink':function(){
          }
     }

 changeUrl.InitWebLink();
```

the above is a code part structure. but i don't understand it well and don't know each line's aim. expect someone can explain it for me. thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a [object literal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Literal_%28computer_science%29) which defines an object with members: `baseUrl`, `getDomain` and `InitWebLink`. Object's members can be accessed using dot-notation, or array-notation: `object.member`, `object["member"]`, so calling `changeUrl.InitWebLink();` you're involving a method of the object.

If you declare an object using literal then every member can be treated as [`public`, `static`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_syntax#Modifiers_2) in traditional class-based OOP.

Answer (score 2):

In `JavaScript`, every object acts like a dictionary.

in the code given changeUrl is initialized with 3 members:

- `baseUrl` - unknown type
- `getDomain` and `InitWebLink` are both methods (function() declaration)

The code follows `JavaScript Object Notation`

References : [JSON (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb299886.aspx) and [JSON (Wikipedia)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript_Object_Notation)

Comment: it is a call to a method named `InitWebLink()`.

Answer (score 0):

It's a definition of an object. `changeUrl` is an object with several member fields and member functions (methods). `baseUrl` is a field, while `getDomain(url)` and `InitWebLink()` are methods which are implemented in place.